# UIPanGestureRecognizer velocity in view could be nil?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

In `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, there is this function to calculate the velocity of the gesture:

```
func velocity(in view: UIView?) -> CGPoint
```

The [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621209-velocity) says:

> **view**
>   The view in whose coordinate system the velocity of the pan gesture is computed.

I notice that `view` could be `nil`, which is a bit strange. Why and when should we use `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it works the same way as [`location(in view: UIView?)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618116-location) does. If you don't pass a view object, then it'll calculate the velocity in window's coordinate system.

> [`location(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitouch/1618116-location)
>
> The view object in whose coordinate system you want the touch located. A custom view that is handling the touch may specify self to get the touch location in its own coordinate system. Pass **nil** to get the touch location in the window’s coordinates.